# How can I send an email?

Tags: linux, email, smtp

This may sound like a bit of a stupid question, but I have an RFC 2822 standard email file:

```
To: Mr Person <person@example.com>
Subject: Finally Figured Out How To Send Emails!
From: Josh
Date: Tue, 20 May 2013 19:05:45
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <style>
            /* Some styles */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- The text -->
    </body>
</html>
```

But how on Earth do I send it to someone? I want to send it from my GMail account, but I can't even figure out how to send it from my computer at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `mail` has got `-a`:

```
mail -a "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" -a "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"-s "Finally Figured Out How To Send Emails!" person@example.com < /tmp/htmlfile.htm
```

Of course your mail must be configured to send emails to the outside world.

Comment: There's no way to have `mail` parse the email file itself?

Comment: well, `cat emailfile.txt | telnet mail.server.com 25`

Comment: I couldn't get `mail` or `telnet` to work for me, but `msmtp` did the trick. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

To send "the mail file" using your computer MTA:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t < your-mail-file-with-headers-and-body
```

or if you want to set envelope sender/bounces to email address:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -fYOU@EXAMPLE.NET -i -t < your-mail-file-with-headers-and-body
```

`-i` - single dot line is not the end of message
`-t` - get recipients list from message headers
Sendmail "look alikes" are provided by othe MTA (Postfix/Exim/...).

You may use an mail client capable to send directly via your external email account (gmail). Take a look at
"[Sending Email from mailx Command in Linux Using Gmail’s SMTP](http://www.fclose.com/b/linux/1411/sending-email-from-mailx-command-in-linux-using-gmails-smtp/)" - as I understand it describes [heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html).